# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown Menu not appearing

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to develop a website. So far, I have 3 pages, all with the same top `navbar`. I am wondering, why won't this page work, like the others. I am sure I have installed everything that needs to be installed, but the menus won't work. What am I doing wrong? Note: I am using Django.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="dropdown" id="menu1">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu1">
            Meet the Team
            <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{% url 'users:team' %}">Lead Developers</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'users:team' %}">Developers</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'users:team' %}">Contributors</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li class="dropdown" id="menu2">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#menu2">
            Choose Your Plan
            <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Protection Plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Assistence Plans</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a class="disable" href="#">Learn About Busness</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'users:question' %}">
            Post a Question
        <i class="icon-globe"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Visit Us
            <i class="icon-plane"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </li>
  </ul>

<!-- Javascript -->

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js">    </script>

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();  


    });
```

Comment: libraries for `.dropdown()`  included? Check browser console for errors

Comment: @DKM yes, everything is there

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: No errors @HieuNguyen

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What does it do? What were you expecting it to do?

Comment: I was expecting a dropdown menu to appear, but all it does is highlights the dropdown link. No menu shows. @DominicRodger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 `'.dropdown-toggle'` links in your code. You can toggle one of them at a time:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('.dropdown-toggle').eq(0).dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/fzNjJ/

Comment: What do you expect when run this code? Dropdown all your dropdown menu? You can dropdown only one at a time.

Comment: Yes I know, but none of them dropdown at all. Only the dropdown link gets highlighted

Comment: Not sure why you had that problem. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hieuh25/fzNjJ/. I noticed that your 3rd link doesn't actually have any dropdown menu.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Thanks for your help! The fiddle really helped me understand.